# Get different results in Sublime Text and terminal when I run python code?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, read-eval-print-loop, python-internals

I am learning *Core Python* and doing an exercise:

> 4-9. Given the following assignments:
>
> a = 10
>   b = 10
>   c = 100
>   d = 100
>   e = 10.0
>   f = 10.0
>
> What is the output of each of the following and why?
>
> a is b
>   c is d
>   e is f

when I did it in sublime text 2, pressed cmd + B to build, I got all True.

```
a = 10
b = 10
c = 100
d = 100
e = 10.0
f = 10.0
print a is b
print c is d
print e is f

Output:  
True
True
True
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

But when I do it in terminal, I got:

```
Output:  
True
True
False # It's what I expect
```

**Why the results are different?**

Comment: Note that all that ST does is tell Python to run the file as a regular script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you already know why the integer values in `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are reused (they are [interned like all small integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)).

The Python bytecode compiler stores immutable literals (such as floats) as constants with the bytecode. When you use the *same literal* more than once in a row, the same constant is reused. That means that `e` and `f` are both assigned the same bytecode constant; the *same `float` object is used for both* and `e is f` is True:

```
>>> import dis
>>> assignment = compile('''\
... e = 10.0
... f = 10.0
... ''', '<stdin>', 'exec')
>>> dis.dis(assignment)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (10.0)
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (e)

  2           6 LOAD_CONST               0 (10.0)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (f)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> assignment.co_consts
(10.0, None)
```

Note how both `LOAD_CONST` instructions use the same index (`0`) to load the floating point object; the constants structure contains just the *one* `float` object.

However, the Python *interactive session* compiles each statement separately; the bytecode compiler doesn't get a chance to re-use the constant, and two distinct objects are stored instead. By the time `f = 10.0` is compiled, `e = 10.0` has been compiled and executed already, and the codeobject for that assignment is already gone.

This is why you see a difference between running the script in one go (as the Sublime Text Build command does) and pasting the code into the Python interactive session.